# How to get an SKView to trigger a method in its parent SKView upon dismissal

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an SKView running for gameplay and want to overlay a smaller SKView when the level is completed (or failed). When the user selects an action (restart, next level, etc) I need to dismiss this SKView (`[self removeFromView]` and trigger an appropriate method in the gameplay SKView. Is this even possible?

Comment: no, you can only have one skview on ios. While technically it won't crash only one view will update in realtime, the other will rarely or never draw its contents

Comment: If I used an SKView (or even a regular ViewController) would it be possible to have the gameScene continue updating?

Comment: Oh, I'm the one answering with the delegate pattern below: You should definitely present a smaller SKScene rather than another SKView. It is the scene that provides the content after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though @nickfalk's answer is suitable, you can also consider using an `NSNotification`. Your parent viewController will be the listener, and the method can be triggered just by posting the applicable notification.

Comment: Hm... custom notifications isn't something I've done before. I'll have to look into this. This does seem like a pretty elegant solution.

Comment: This worked and only took a few lines of code! Unfortunately, the smaller SKScene still replaces everything on screen instead of just overlaying. That's a separate question though. Maybe I shouldn't be using an SKScene after all.

Comment: Just for reference, I couldn't get a smaller SKView or UIViewController, so I ended up creating a smaller UIView and adding the necessary subviews to it. I still use this NSNotification solution to communicate between my instance of UIView and gameScene. userData in the notification is how I communicate which button in the UIView was clicked.

Comment: You can't use an SKScene on top of another... You need a view on which to render it. You could have played that scene on the view that u added.. But, as long as you are getting what you want, any implementation is fine.

Comment: Oh I hadn't considered doing that. I've read in various places that you can't have two SKScenes running simultaneously. I haven't tested it myself though. I'd like the gameScene to continue running its SKEmitterNodes while the levelEnd scene pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a delegate protocol for the "levelCompleted" scene:

```
@protocol YOURlevelCompletedSceneDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)touchesBeganOnScene:(YOURlevelCompletedScene *)scene;
@end
```

Give the levelCompletedScene a delegate obviously:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject <YOURlevelCompletedSceneDelegate> *delegate;
```

Make your gameScene adhere to the protocol:

```
@interface YOURGameScene () <YOURlevelCompletedSceneDelegate>
```

Make it the levelCompletedScene's delegate whenever you set this up:

```
levelCompletedScene.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the delegate method somewhere in your gameScene and do whatever you want:

```
- (void)touchesBeganOnScene:(YOURlevelCompletedScene *)scene{
   // enjoy!
}
```

Comment: This makes sense though it seems so roundabout. I'll try it out soon. Thanks!

Comment: I see what you mean, as the "plumbing" might seem a bit extensive at first. It keeps things clean though as the levelCompletedScene doesn't have to have any knowledge about its parent. It will also pan out beautifully if you want to use the levelCompleted scene elsewhere, perhaps displaying a different set of information.